# Redmine: Plugins not working

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I tried to install Redmine plugins on my Raspberry. Since there wasn't any "Plugins" folder I made one and cloned the plugins repository on that folder, but after migrating and restarting the apache webserver the plugins didn't appeared.
What I did wrong?

Plugins what I installed:

- Agile_Dwarf
- Redmine_Monitoring_Controlling
- Progressive_Projects_List
- Timelog_Timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I tried to install it to `/var/www/redmine` and not to `/usr/share/redmine`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points to consider:

1. Did you migrate your redmine database as well ?
2. Is the path of the new redmine installation different from the old path ?
3. You may need to install the plugins one by one again. After installing one plugin you should create the file restart.txt in the tmp folder of your redmine installation. This will restart redmine itself

Comment: It's a fresh install. The migration script is what was on the plugin's installation page and there isn't any tmp folder.

Comment: Well if its a fresh install, then you should install the plugins one by one by following the plugin installation guide. You can create a tmp folder in the redmine root installation folder. After you install one plugin you should create an empty file called restart.txt inside the tmp folder. This will restart redmine. You should then check if your plugin is showing on the plugins page. Do this for each plugin